# Trouble setting up spyder 4.2.1 on macOS BIGsur

Tags: python, pandas, macos, anaconda, spyder

i hope this question somehow fits in here.
Short: Can't install Spyder 4.2.1 using anaconda. However, I can install stand alone Spyder 4.2.1 but then i don't know how to install packages as the terminal/pip won't find the python from the stand alone Spyder.

long: Spyder 4.2.1 seems to be the first version that is supported on BIGsur. However, when I installed anaconda, it came with Spyder 4.1.5. I tried conda -update Spyder in the terminal and I got Spyder 4.2.0. This version is still super laggy and has high typing latency in the editor.
Trying the same again shows latest version already installed. Same for trying: conda -update anaconda.
Spyder4.2.1 was only released a few days ago. Is it possible it takes a while until anaconda supports it? If so, how long would it take (days, weeks or months?). My google searches had no results regarding this.

Since 4.2.0 the Spyder developers recommend the stand alone installers, which I understand as using Spyder without anaconda. I installed Spyder 4.2.1 and the typing in the editor was indeed super smooth. But now i couldn't properly install packages like pandas.
I also noticed that when i run spyder from anaconda the first line in the console indicates python 3.8 but when i run the stand alone spyder4.2.1 it says python 3.9.
The terminal only "recognizes" the 3.8 version. At least I can run Python3.8 in the Terminal but trying to run Python3.9 gives zsh: command not found error. (when it comes to install packages, developers recommend conda again. But this only updates the built in Spyder packages not the stand alone Spyder...

I realized the Python3.9 version is located in the spyder.app-file. I am super new to macOS and was quiet surprised when i found out, that what i thought was a launching icon was also a directory. Anyway using pip -install seems to only install packages for the python3.8 version.
With --target I tried to install the package into the spyder.app directory. Now I'm afraid it installs the wrong version of pandas. In the terminal it said it installed pandas 0.24 which is quiet outdated. I have also Python 2.7 installed and I feel like the pandas version i got matches python2.7.
So i tried to install the python3.9 version (using: python3.9 -m pip install), but since the terminal doesn't recognize this version it says command does not exist.

The message from Spyder after "import pandas" is around 100 lines, i copied the red highlighted ones:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.tslibs.base'
KeyError: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion'
KeyError: 'pandas._libs.missing'
KeyError: 'pandas._libs.hashtable'
KeyError: 'pandas._libs.interval'
```

Has anyone installed Spyder 4.2.1 using anaconda or knows how to install packages for the stand alone version?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to change spyders4.2.1 python environment to the python  I installed seperately. Now I can install packages with pip install.